# Clickable dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

This is fiddle of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/WNmff/1/
It's a bit stripped down... originally there are 15 list items + the fiddle doesn't show the way this really function.
I was trying to combine different elements (CSS drop-down menu, accordion...) to make a menu that works with clicking and not with hover. (it might look a bit patched up ^^)
However:

- if I click multiple list items once (without disabling them) they remain active and when I hover over them they appear on their own;
- if I click one item and then move the mouse over another one the sub-menu disappears;
- List item
- when i click on the lower items (which need a bit scrolling to get to) the page scrolls automatically back to top.

There are probably more problems, but this are the ones that are really annoying and prevent the site from functioning like it was requested.

Thanks in advance...